# Using LIBLINEAR to train 2D features

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, liblinear

This is my first machine learning exercise, and I want to use LIBLINEAR to train on some data. The training data that I have worked is stored as a multidimensional matrix of size *m*x*m*x*n*, where there are n instances of *m*x*m* matrices, with each cell in the *m*x*m* matrix containing a value between 1-255 to indicate pixel values.

Included with this data is a *n*x1 vector of labels. However, trying to use the LIBLINEAR function train(training_labels, sparse(training_data)) yields an error. I think its because training_data is a 3d matrix. What steps am I missing or not understanding? I assumed that since the training_labels is *n*x1, each value in the training_labels vector maps to a *m*x*m* matrix of data. Is that not the case?

Thanks!

Comment: So essentially an `m x m` matrix in your data has a single label. One way is to convert the `m x m` matrix into a row vector (by doing `(M(:)).'`). Then use that as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one m x m array is one feature vector, but it has the form of a matrix. liblinear probably can't deal with this. As written in the comment, you have to change the data format. If A is your 3d array, then

```
reshape(A, m * m, n)
```

gives you a 2d matrix with m² rows and n columns.